# Having trouble pivoting this data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

MS Server 2012

The following query returns the correct data but i need to pivot it and my attempts are failing, any hep would be appreciated..

Query...

`SELECT 
    TrialSampleID,
    ReferenceReadID,
    Reference_Antibiotic,
    CONCAT(Reference_Qualifier, ' ', Reference_MIC, ' ug/ml') AS 'MIC'
FROM 
    dbo.ClinicalTrial
    JOIN dbo.ReferenceDataPointers ON ClinicalTrial.ID = ReferenceDataPointers.ClinicalTrialID
    JOIN dbo.ReferencePlates ON ReferenceDataPointers.ReferenceSetID = ReferencePlates.ReferenceSetID
    JOIN dbo.ReferenceReads ON ReferencePlates.ID = ReferenceReads.ReferencePlateID
    JOIN dbo.ReferenceMICs ON ReferenceReads.ID = ReferenceMICs.ReferenceReadID
WHERE 
    TrialSampleID NOT LIKE 'REF-%' 
    AND SpecimenSource LIKE 'Clinical%'
    AND Reference_ValidAntibiotic = 'True`'

Result...

```
TrialSampleID |ReferenceReadID |Reference_Antibiotic          |MIC          
CC-200001     | 4077           |Amikacin                      | = 8 ug/ml
CC-200001     | 4077           |Ampicillin                    | > 64 ug/ml
CC-200001     | 4077           |Aztreonam                     | > 64 ug/ml
CC-200001     | 4077           |Cefazolin                     | > 16 ug/ml
CC-200001     | 4077           |Cefepime                      | = 64 ug/ml
CC-200001     | 4077           |Ceftazidime                   | > 64 ug/ml
CC-200001     | 4077           |Ceftazidime/Avibactam         | ≤ 2 ug/ml
CC-200001     | 4077           |Ertapenem                     | ≤ 0.125 ug/ml
CC-200001     | 4077           |Gentamicin                    | > 32 ug/ml
CC-200001     | 4077           |Levofloxacin                  | = 8 ug/ml
CC-200001     | 4077           |Meropenem                     | ≤ 0.125 ug/ml
CC-200001     | 4077           |Meropenem/Vaborbactam         | ≤ 0.5 ug/ml
CC-200001     | 4077           |Piperacillin/Tazobactam       | = 128 ug/ml
CC-200001     | 4077           |Trimethoprim/Sulfamethoxazole | > 8 ug/ml
```

The block repeats 6 times for each TrialSampleID giving 6 MICs

I would like the data in the following form but end up with NULL in the MIC column when i pivot the data.

Desired...

```
TrialSampleID |ReferenceReadID |Reference_Antibiotic          |MIC1             |MIC2               |MIC3
CC-200001     | 4077           |Amikacin                      | = 8 ug/ml       |   = 8 ug/ml       |   = 8 ug/ml
CC-200001     | 4077           |Ampicillin                    | > 64 ug/ml      |   > 64 ug/ml      |   > 64 ug/ml
CC-200001     | 4077           |Aztreonam                     | > 64 ug/ml      |   > 64 ug/ml      |   > 64 ug/ml
CC-200001     | 4077           |Cefazolin                     | > 16 ug/ml      |   > 16 ug/ml      |   > 16 ug/ml
CC-200001     | 4077           |Cefepime                      | = 64 ug/ml      |   = 64 ug/ml      |   = 64 ug/ml
CC-200001     | 4077           |Ceftazidime                   | > 64 ug/ml      |   > 64 ug/ml      |   > 64 ug/ml
CC-200001     | 4077           |Ceftazidime/Avibactam         | ≤ 2 ug/ml       |   ≤ 2 ug/ml       |   ≤ 2 ug/ml
CC-200001     | 4077           |Ertapenem                     | ≤ 0.125 ug/ml   |   ≤ 0.125 ug/ml   |   ≤ 0.125 ug/ml
CC-200001     | 4077           |Gentamicin                    | > 32 ug/ml      |   > 32 ug/ml      |   > 32 ug/ml
CC-200001     | 4077           |Levofloxacin                  | = 8 ug/ml       |   = 8 ug/ml       |   = 8 ug/ml
CC-200001     | 4077           |Meropenem                     | ≤ 0.125 ug/ml   |   ≤ 0.125 ug/ml   |   ≤ 0.125 ug/ml
CC-200001     | 4077           |Meropenem/Vaborbactam         | ≤ 0.5 ug/ml     |   ≤ 0.5 ug/ml     |   ≤ 0.5 ug/ml
CC-200001     | 4077           |Piperacillin/Tazobactam       | = 128 ug/ml     |   = 128 ug/ml     |   = 128 ug/ml
CC-200001     | 4077           |Trimethoprim/Sulfamethoxazole | > 8 ug/ml       |   > 8 ug/ml       |   > 8 ug/ml
```

tried...

```
PIVOT(  
    MIN(ReferenceReadID)
    FOR MIC IN (
                MIC1,
                MIC2,
                MIC3,
                MIC4,
                MIC5,
                MIC6
                )   
    ) pivoted
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved it, Thandk D-Shih for the insight...

```
SELECT  TrialSampleID,
        Reference_Antibiotic,
        MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN MIC END) 'MIC1',
        MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN MIC END) 'MIC2',
        MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN MIC END) 'MIC3',
        MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN MIC END) 'MIC4',
        MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 5 THEN MIC END) 'MIC5',
        MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 6 THEN MIC END) 'MIC6'
FROM (
        SELECT 
            TrialSampleID,
            Reference_Antibiotic,
            CONCAT(Reference_Qualifier, ' ', Reference_MIC, ' ug/ml') AS 'MIC',
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TrialSampleID, Reference_Antibiotic ORDER BY TrialSampleID, Reference_Antibiotic) rn
        FROM 
            dbo.ClinicalTrial
            JOIN dbo.ReferenceDataPointers ON ClinicalTrial.ID = ReferenceDataPointers.ClinicalTrialID
            JOIN dbo.ReferencePlates ON ReferenceDataPointers.ReferenceSetID = ReferencePlates.ReferenceSetID
            JOIN dbo.ReferenceReads ON ReferencePlates.ID = ReferenceReads.ReferencePlateID
            JOIN dbo.ReferenceMICs ON ReferenceReads.ID = ReferenceMICs.ReferenceReadID
        WHERE 
            TrialSampleID NOT LIKE 'REF-%' 
            AND SpecimenSource LIKE 'Clinical%'
            AND Reference_ValidAntibiotic = 'True'
    ) t1
GROUP BY TrialSampleID, Reference_Antibiotic
ORDER BY TrialSampleID, Reference_Antibiotic
```